# Paperclip Processor Operate on S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am trying to create a custom `Paperclip::Processor` that integrates with an external web service (the processor will call the web service whenever a new file is uploaded). The external service needs the file to be present in S3 and will handle uploading the processed versions to S3 automatically.

Can this be done using a custom `Paperclip::Processor` or should it be done with an ActiveRecord callback? If a `Paperclip::Processor` will work, what is the best way to trigger the upload? Ideally I'd like to do a processor, but the requirement is that the original file **MUST** be uploaded to S3 first. I have taken a look at using `after_create` calls, but it sometimes seems to conflict with the `after_create` used in paperclip. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to create a local copy of the file. If it's on S3 it will be downloaded.

```
tmp_file = @model.attached_file.to_file => TempFile<...>
```

You can then do your operations on this TempFile. When you're don:

```
@model.attached_file = tmp_file
@model.save
```

Edit: misread your question. You can use the `before_post_process` and `after_post_process` hooks to perform tasks before or after the file was processed.

```
class Model < AR::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar

  after_post_process :ping_webservice

  private

  def ping_webservice
    # Do your magic here.
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Ariejan. Thanks for the response, but the `after_post_process` hook occurs before the file is uploaded to S3 so this doesn't work.

Comment: Just use `after_save` then and check if the avatar url is present.

Comment: Thanks Garrett. Do you know a way to a force a specific `after_save` to be executed last? I looked through the paperclip documentation and realized it uses the `after_save` callback as well so sometimes the file won't be in S3.

Comment: OK, I'm actually going through and working at modifying paperclip at this point. Couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 2):

I dealt with a similar issue recently, and it was with the after_save callback. I managed to fix my problem by defining paperclip (has_attached_file ...) after I defined my after_save. This way, paperclip's callback will fire after mine.